# .NET How to catch precaught exceptions on separate class/form

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, error-handling, exception

I have a very large application, which I would rather not rewrite.

I made a dll/class which logs each form opened & Closed inside the main MDI of the application (without adding more than 5 lines to the application itself).
I used IMessageFilter/PreFilterMessage and several other tricks for this task

Now I would like to add code inside which would log all exceptions caught inside those forms. (Without modifying everything).

This DLL once complete will be moved to multiple projects, thus I cannot edit much in the main application, or make DLL application specific.

Basically, when an exception somewhere in the application which is handled, I want my DLL to know about it.

Any ideas? (With exception of "you can't do that")

Comment: Are you referencing said DLL inside the main application? Do you have a common error handler method in your application? If so, why not make a call inside said common error handler to a method in the referenced DLL passing the exception object? That way is not application specific (every other application referencing said dll can pass exceptions to be logged) and you would need to modify little.

Comment: You might be able to use [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/) for this somehow but natively there is no way to know an exception was thrown and caught somewhere else.

Comment: Isn't AppDomain.FirstChanceException what you are looking for?

Comment: Article about FirstChanceException: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/05/01/working-with-exceptions.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll have a look at this first chance exception- I was really more interested in reading the already caught exception which we display to the user. The current application has many small parts that were build by several developers over the past 5 years, so there is no common error handler method.  The only common code is (try..catch ex as exception) blocks. Was hoping to copy the ex.tostring every time one gets triggered somewhere. The other applications may have a common error handler, but I am trying to make this as generic as possible

Comment: So, to update - The FirstChanceException has been giving minimal data in terms where the errors originate from, unless I'm missing something. Is there a way to show where it was originated (Stacktrace) currently it just says myapp.vhost.exe as host, and for stacktrace it is the last function (which is usually a microsoft function)

Comment: **Stacktrace Example:   
From FCE::**    `System.Data.ConstraintCollection.AddForeignKeyConstraint(ForeignKeyConstraint constraint)`
    
**From Try Catch Block::**    `at System.Data.ConstraintCollection.AddForeignKeyConstraint(ForeignKeyConstraint constraint)
   at System.Data.ConstraintCollection.Add(Constraint constraint, Boolean addUniqueWhenAddingForeign)
   at System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataSetRelationCollection.AddCore(DataRelation relation)
   at System.Data.DataRelationCollection.Add(DataRelation relation)
   at My.Application.FormTest.LoadData()`

Answer (score -1):

You can use Logger library. This library provides easy logging.

Comment: Becaues you mention a library (or a type of library possibly?) without linking to it, you say it provides easy logging which isn't what the OP wanted and you don't clarify what makes it "easy" (almost all log libraries are easy to use).